# How to catch ng-flow event with angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with angular JS 1.5.6 and I am using components. With components there is no more $scope. My question is how do I catch ng-flow event without $scope.

On [ng-flow documentation](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow), the developper says we can catch events like this :

```
$scope.$on('flow::fileAdded', function (event, $flow, flowFile) {
  event.preventDefault();//prevent file from uploading
});
```

But with components there is no more $scope.. Is there a work around to be able to catch ng-flow events?